# Qual status posso retornar numa tentativa de enviar um formulário sem um TOKEN?

Tags: php, laravel, http, http-status, csrf

Eu gostaria de saber qual é o `status http` que devo retornar em minha aplicação caso alguém esteja tentando forjar uma requisição via formulário.

A aplicação que desenvolvi é feita no `Laravel 4` e eu estou usando aquele `CSRF_TOKEN`.

O `CSRF_TOKEN` serve para poder prefinir ataques de [Cross-Site Request Forgery](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

Seria correto utilizar alguns dos métodos como `400 - Bad Request`, `503 - internal server error`, ou `403 - unauthorized access`, caso haja uma tentativa de requisição forjada? Ou simplesmente, não devo retornar nenhum `status http` ou erro que seja?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tendo como base a [lista de código de status HTTP](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_c%C3%B3digos_de_status_HTTP) e suas descrições eu recomendo.

### 400 - Requisição inválida (Bad request)

> **400 Requisição inválida (Bad Request)**
>   O pedido não pode ser entregue devido à sintaxe incorreta.

O fato de faltar um parâmetro, o TOKEN, esta mensagem é a que melhor descreve o erro que ocorreu durante a requisição

### Porque não `403 Proibido (unauthorized access)`?

> **403 Proibido (unauthorized access)**
>   O pedido foi um pedido legal, mas o servidor está recusando a responder a ela. 
>   Ao contrário de um `401 - Não autorizado(Unauthorized)`, autenticação não fará diferença.

No caso não é um acesso negado à uma requisição ou diretório e sim a falta de um parâmetro na requisição, desta forma a falta de privilégios não retrata da melhor forma a falha na requisição.

### Porque não `503 - internal server error`?

> **503 Serviço indisponível (Service Unavailable)**
>   O servidor está em manutenção ou não consegue dar conta dos processamentos de recursos devido à sobrecarga do sistema. Isto deve ser uma condição temporária.

Como de fato seu servidor não apresenta nenhum erro esta não é a melhor resposta para um acesso indevido a uma requisição.

Comment: Amigo, coloquei 414 errôneamente. a intenção era colocar 400. Será que poderia editar o último item?

Comment: OK, editarei a resposta

Comment: No caso a 400 passa a ser uma boa opção também, já que a falta de um parâmetro (o tokem) gera um erro na requisição, assim o usuário saberá q errou algo na requisição e essa passa a ser melhorque `403`