# Qual status HTTP retornar para um token expirado?

Tags: http, http-status

Tenho uma aplicação onde o usuário pode solicitar um token para recuperação de senha. Porém eu dou a esse token um prazo de 2 horas.

Quando o token expira, quero retornar um erro ao cliente, demonstrando pra ele o detalhe do ocorrido, porém tenho uma pequena dúvida:

Já fiz uma pergunta parecida anteriormente sobre Status HTTP, porém o contexto é um pouco diferente agora:

[Qual status posso retornar numa tentativa de enviar um formulário sem um TOKEN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50625/qual-status-posso-retornar-numa-tentativa-de-enviar-um-formul%C3%A1rio-sem-um-token)

Qual é o status HTTP que deveria ser retornado para um caso desse?

Pensei em retornar um `400`, mas no caso `400` parece estar mais relacionado a um parâmetro inválido de uma url ou formulário.

Comment: Quem negativou a questão poderia esclarecer de que forma a pergunta possa ser melhorada?

Comment: Pensando assim, "400 parece estar mais relacionado a um parâmetro inválido.". Se encararmos o tempo de vida do token como um parâmetro, poderia muito bem ser uma bad request mesmo.

Comment: @MarceloBoni Parâmetro de URL [ou de formulário], eu quis dizer. Ou seja, eu geralmente usaria o 400 para poder indicar que o cara deixou de colocar o parâmetro `id` na url, que seria necessário para gerar um PDF, por exemplo.

Comment: Só comentando, o linkedin a alguns anos emitia um código `HTTP 999` quando tentavamos acessar os dados publicos sem o uso da API deles, claro que eles mudaram isso hoje, mas achei muito criativo, basicamente uma piada com quem não usava a API xD (detalhes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27571486/1518921)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Resposta curta**

Se o *token* faz parte do corpo da requisição, 403 (ou 404), mas se é enviado como *token* de autenticação, 401.

## [400](https://http.cat/400.jpg) Bad Request

Eu definitivamente não iria com uma resposta [**400: Bad Request**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1). Tal erro indica que a requisição falhou por erros no cliente, que gerou uma requisição que não foi compreendida em sua integridade pelo servidor. Se você gosta de personificar as coisas, seria como se o servidor respondesse:

— *Meu caro, eu recebi sua requisição, mas não entendi o que está requerendo, portanto não irei entregar qualquer conteúdo de forma a evitar mal-entendidos.*

Mas no meu entendimento, a requisição estaria correta - dentro do contexto abordado na pergunta -, apenas o *token* que não seria mais válido.

> The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot
> or    will not process the request due to something that is perceived
> to be    a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid
> request    message framing, or deceptive request routing).

## [403](https://http.cat/403.jpg) Forbidden

Eu acredito que a resposta [**403: Forbidden**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3) faz mais sentido aqui, pois ela indica que o servidor entendeu qual foi a requisição realizada, porém não gerou o *payload* esperado, isto é, não efetivou a requisição, devido à dados incoerentes. Além disso, o servidor estará explicitamente informando ao cliente para não tentar novamente com os mesmos dados e, se realmente necessitar efetivar a ação, deverá atualizar os dados enviados.

— *Meu caro, entendi o que você solicitou, mas infelizmente não posso processar seu pedido, pois algo errado não está certo. Por favor, confira as informações que me passou.*

> The 403 (Forbidden) status code indicates that the server
> understood    the request but refuses to authorize it.  A server that
> wishes to    make public why the request has been forbidden can
> describe that    reason in the response payload (if any).
>
> If authentication credentials were provided in the request, the server considers them insufficient to grant access.  The client SHOULD NOT automatically repeat the request with the same credentials.  The client MAY repeat the request with new or different credentials.  However, a request might be forbidden for reasons unrelated to the credentials.
>
> An origin server that wishes to "hide" the current existence of a forbidden target resource MAY instead respond with a status code of 404 (Not Found).

## [404](https://http.cat/404.jpg) Not Found

E, assim como a RFC comenta, dependendo dos requisitos de sua aplicação, é possível que você não queira expor a arquitetura da mesma em uma requisição falha. Se for o caso de você não desejar expor que o recurso de recuperação de senha exista nesta URL, você pode retornar a resposta [**404: Not Found**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4) que, ao meu ver, pode ser interpretada de duas maneiras, dependendo da origem da requisição. Se a requisição partiu da sua própria aplicação, que sabe, com certeza, que o recurso de recuperação de senha existe nesta URL, você pode interpretar a resposta 404 como "*token* não localizado", o que é verdade, pois se ele expirou ele, idealmente, não existe mais. Já, se a requisição parte, por exemplo, de um usuário malicioso tentando modificar a senha de outros usuários, a resposta 404 pode confundí-lo achando que o recurso não existe nesta URL.

## [409](https://http.cat/409.jpg) Conflict

A resposta [**409: Conflict**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8) também acho que não se encaixe aqui, pois geralmente está associada à atualização de um recurso que foi modificado por outras fontes no processo. Algo como: eu busquei um registro para edição e, enquanto faço as alterações necessárias, outro usuário altera o registro. As informações originais que eram base para as minhas alterações não são mais as persistidas no recurso, o que pode/deve gerar conflito informando-me que o recurso foi atualizado e que devo rever minhas alterações. Caso semelhante quando dois usuários alteram um mesmo arquivo em disco.

## [401](https://http.cat/401.jpg) Unauthorized

Além disso, se você utilizar o *token* como forma de **autenticação** do cliente, a resposta [**401: Unauthorized**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1) é uma opção. Por exemplo, para exibir o formulário de recuperação de senha você faz:

```
GET /esqueci-minha-senha HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic e8d95a51f3af4a3b134bf6bb680a213a
```

E o *token* de autenticação não for válido, a resposta 401 será aceitável. Como comentado em outras respostas, há o requisito previsto na especificação que uma resposta 401 **deve** incluir o cabeçalho `WWW-Authenticate` contendo um *desafio*.

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="ForgotPassword"
```

Há uma descrição em [*Challenge-response authentication*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/challenge) sobre a definição do desafio:

> In security protocols, a challenge is some data sent to the client by
> the server in order to generate a different response each time.
> Challenge-response protocols are one way to fight against [replay
> attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack) where an attacker listens to the previous messages and resends
> them at a later time to get the same credentials as the original
> message.
>
> The [HTTP authentication protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication) is challenge-response based, though
> the "Basic" protocol isn't using a real challenge (the realm is always
> the same).

Porém, se o *token* de recuperação é enviado como parte do corpo da requisição, não vejo sentido em retornar a 401, e sim a 403 (ou 404, como supracitado).

## [498](https://www.scienceandnonduality.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/schrodingers-cat.png) Invalid Token

Quanto a utilizar códigos não padronizados, tal como o [**498: Invalid Token**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#Unofficial_codes) eu julgaria válido apenas quando sua aplicação interagir apenas com outras aplicações suas ou de terceiros muito bem documentadas, que deixam explícito que esperam ou suportam tais respostas. Navegadores não se classificam como tal, então acho arriscado retornar para ele uma resposta fora das especificações, até pelo fato de correr o risco de cada navegador interpretar de uma forma distinta. Se seu servidor possui, por exemplo, um [*gateway*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227907/5878) de entrada, acho perfeitamente válido você utilizar qualquer que for a resposta, mesmo as não previstas pela RFC, desde que o *gateway* saiba resolver tais respostas para uma dentro das especificações.

<sub>*Nenhum gato foi maltratado durante a elaboração desta resposta.*</sub>

Comment: Esse comentário no final dos _gatos não maltratados_ foi ótimo!

Comment: Para TOKEN creio que **não** correto seria o `Basic` né?

Answer (score 3):

O ideal seria retornar um `401 Unauthorized` no http-status da sua requisição.

Aqui nesse site tem um material super bacana falando sobre isso e suas possibilidades:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status.

Achei uma pergunta parecida com a sua:

- [Token Expired - JSON REST API - Error Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855297/token-expired-json-rest-api-error-code)

Comment: E como resolve essa questão que é requisito do 401? _"The response MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header field (section 14.47) containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource. The client MAY repeat the request with a suitable Authorization header field (section 14.8)."_

Comment: Não é a mais votada, mas no link mencionado tem alternativas sugerindo o 400 para garantir não ter desentendimento. Não seria mais adequado (eu acho que não, pq nao foi bem um bad request).Por que não seriam, por exemplo 406 Not acceptable, 409 Conflict ou 412 Precondition failed? (tou tentando entender a motivação da escolha do 401, pq nenhuma das 2 respostas dadas deixou bem claro isso, apesar de uma ter positivos e a outra negativos apresentando praticamente as mesmas coisas)

Comment: @Bacco Não entendi bem o que seria *challenge* nesse contexto, mas os exemplos que vi do WWW-Authenticate parecem simples. O mais complexo é o da própria RFC: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7235#section-4.1

Comment: @Bacco , pelo que entendi (do link da MDN) então, o 401 é uma espécie de 403 que pode ser revertido após conseguir uma autenticação, enquanto que o 403 é erro não reversível, não tem como autenticar. Entendi corretamente?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado eu não consegui chegar numa conclusão satisfatória (por isso nem  arrisquei resposta). Tou levantando as problemáticas pra gente ver se chega numa resposta mais embasada (dentro do possível)

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o status `400 - Bad request` seja correto, já que a solicitação tem um token inválido, logo ela também é inválida.

O status `401 - Unauthorized` pode ser uma opção se você quer algo mais específico, se o token passado na requisição é a forma de acessar o recurso e esse token expirou, então você não tem autorização para acessar esse recurso.

Se não tiver problemas pode usar o status não oficial [`498 - Invalid Token`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#Unofficial_codes)

Comment: Não existe gato para o 498 (vide https://http.cat/498.jpg), então não o conhecia. Mas para 400, vide https://http.cat/400.jpg; para os curiosos: [401](https://http.cat/401.jpg)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado tentei usar o 498, e o navegador  retorna "498 Unknow error"